# Substract only month and year in c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have one field in my database that keep the start date of the employee.

And I want to know how many employee that has one year anniversary in this month?

Example, If the employee start work on `07/12/2012` so if the current date is `01/12/2013`, It is his/her anniversary.

This is the format string of start date of each employee `07/12/2012`. And I want to compare only the month and the year(not date).

Could any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: That's not a format string - it is a formatted date.

Comment: Can you explain [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It is the date format but I input it as a string to my database. I don't know how to calculate the month between the current month and year of the current date with the field start date in my database, like `12/2013 - 12/2012 = 1`. If  the result equal 1 so it is the anniversary of the employee in this month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions in Transact-SQL (supposing, you use MSSQL). ([See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx))

So if you have a DATETIME field `startdate` in your table

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE MONTH(startdate)=12 AND YEAR(startdate)=2012
```

will get you all employees having 1-year anniversary in Dec 2012.

**EDIT**

If your table contains the date as string, you can either use `SUBSTRING(startdate,3,2)` to get the month (as string!) and `SUBSTRING(startdate,6,4)` for the year, or you use the [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928) or [PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316) functions to convert it to a datetime (and then use `MONTH` and `YEAR` as described above)

**2nd Edit**

With Linq to SQL it would be

```
var result = from employees e 
             select e 
             where e.startdate.Month==DateTime.Now.Month 
                   && e.startdate.Year==DateTime.Now.Year;
```

(still assuming the `startdate` column in you database has `DATETIME` data type ...)

Comment: So `WHERE MONTH(startdate)= MONTH(currentdate) AND YEAR(startdate) - YEAR(currentdate) = 1` would give the result the OP wants.

Comment: I'm using LinQ to SQL. Thanks.

Comment: @socheata You should've mentioned that fact in your question :) I edited my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

**Its very easy:**

```
SELECT  *
From    Member m
WHERE
        MONTH(m.CreatedAt) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

**Also if you want right next year anniversary, you can use:**

```
SELECT  *
From    Member m
WHERE
        MONTH(m.CreatedAt) = MONTH(GETDATE()) and
        YEAR(m.CreatedAt) = YEAR(GETDATE()) +1
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle it in SQL try

```
SELECT *  FROM  [dbo].[Employee]
where (DATEPART(mm, [StartDate]) = Month(GetDate())
AND DATEPART(dd, [StartDate]) = Day(GetDate())
```

in C#

```
var aniveraries = from employee in employees
                  where
                        employee.StartDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                        employee.StartDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                  select employee;
```